# xmlhttpRequest to open Excel (xlsx) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, xmlhttprequest

Hi is it possible to open an excel file and manipulate the data using xmlhttprequest or jquery with javascript?... this is for a web application.
Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Good luck writing an Excel parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You would need to interrogate the XLSX file and parse the contents using something like [SheetJS](http://sheetjs.com/sexql/). This would of course only parse the content and allow you to display it. You would also need to either find and couple or build your own manipulation interface.

SheetJS will read and write XLSX files and allows parsing via AJAX. If your requirement is to recreate all Excel functionality in a browser then you're going to have a tough time.

If you simply want to open and edit worksheet cell content you could probably quite quickly create some translation code to recreate the cell layout of an Excel Worksheet in a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)-style component configured for in-cell editing.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I just want to take the values stored in the cells of the excel file, then store those values in a multi-dimensional array on Javascript, so I can use those values later.